Issue while running the Maria DB script docker-composer. Can't initialize batchreadline may be the input source is a directory or a block device
Part of docker-compose file:

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.8.3
    # Uncomment below when on Mac M1
    # platform: linux/arm64/v8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /opt/airflow/dags/scripts/mysql_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_schema.sql

Trying to run this script when docker start but geting this error:
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_schema.sql
ERROR: Can't initialize batch readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.
mysql_init.sql. Please let me know what I am doing wrong in this regard or am I missing something?

Does the mysql_init.sql script exist in that exact absolute directory /opt/airflow/... on the host system?  If it doesn't, Docker will create a directory with that name, and you'll get that symptom.

the absolute directory is airflow_ETL/dags/scripts/mysql_init.sql

The after updating the path to
volumes:
- ./dags/scripts/mysql_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_schema.sql
I can't see those error but looks like the script is not executed? What to do now?

The init script only runs the very first time the database container starts up.  Do you need to docker-compose down -v to delete the storage associated with the database?  (Using your application framework's database-migration system might be more flexible: it won't be tied to Docker and it won't have this "only on initial setup" restriction.)

mysql_native_password is the default auth, so not sure why this is aarch64 only, or needed at all really. Also 10.8.3 is EOL. Maybe mariadb:lts as the latest LTS version. MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE: 1 might be a good env to use if it isn't fixed on the version, even if it is its a good reminder.
